# SQL Server : Storing Hierarchical ACL Data

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, hierarchical

I would like implement a database containing hierarchical acl data

My tables

- `USERS`: idUser,username,...
- `GROUPS`: idGroups,name...
- `GROUPSENTITIES`: idGroup, idChild, childType (1 for users, 2 from groups)
- `ROLES` : idRole,name...
- `ROLESENTITIES`: idRole, IsDeny, idChild, childType (1 for users, 2 from groups)
- Every user can belong to 0 or more groups
- Every group can belong to 0 or more groups
- Every user and every group can belong to 0 or more roles and roles can be allowed or denied
- If an explicit deny is found, role is denied

How can I store this kind of data? Is my design correct?

Is it possible retrieve a list of users with all allowed roles?

Can you please write me a query (T-SQL based) for extract this information from db

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can write the tables as you would expect.  For instance, to get all the users in a group, when there are hierarchical groups, you would use a recursive CTE.  Assume the group table is set up as:

```
create table groups (
    groupid int,
    member_userId int,
    member_groupid int,
    check (member_userId is NULL or member_groupid is null)
);

with usergroups as (
      select groupid, member_userid, 1 as level
      from groups
      union all
      select g.groupid, users.member_userid, 1+level
      from users u join
           groups g
           on u.member_groupid = g.groupid
    )
select *
from usergroups;
```

Comment: can you explain better please? what about roles? GROUPENTITIES is a crosstable for joining GROUPS and USERS but also GROUPS with GROUPS (if childType=1 the childId contains a userId, if childType=2 thenn childId contains a groupId). how can i query this structure with cte?

Comment: sorry but cannot post DDL of table cause column name are localized... :(